# Is it "required login" or "login required"?

Tags: grammar, phrase-choice

I was testing some authentification API, and it returned me

> REQUIRED LOGIN

It feels a little bit odd here. Shouldn't it be *LOGIN REQUIRED*?

Or are both grammatically correct? If so, as a standalone phrase that is a response code, which one is better to use here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither is a complete sentence

The first is a noun phrase which would mean something like "This (or that) is a required login"  The meaning is rather unclear: does login mean a "login name" or a "login in process".  Perhaps the context makes it clear, perhaps not.

The second would mean something like "A login is required", which I suppose would make more sense in most contexts.

Neither is particularly friendly but the second form is probably what you want to say in this context.